# Find sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)$ such that $(b_n)$ is positive and decreasing, the sum over $(a_n)$ converges, and the sum over $(a_nb_n)$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Also, we assume $(b_n)$ converges to 0. This is an exercise from Johnsonbaugh's Foundations of Mathematical Analysis. I already determined that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ cannot converge absolutely or by the alternating series test, so both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ might have to have some relatively special properties (at least compared with convergent series that a relative beginner might be familiar with).

Comment: It follows from summation by parts that if the $b_n\to 0$, then the series $\sum a_nb_n$ will converge. So you'd better look at examples where $b_n\not\to 0$.

Comment: Well, since $(b_n)$ is bounded below it converges. Now that I'm reading it it seems like $(a_nb_n)$ actually has to converge undwr the stated conditions and I might have written the problem incorrectly.

Comment: Nevermind, I just looked again and the only mistake I made is that $b_n$ is assumed to converge to zero in addition to the other conditions. Is there an error in the book?

Comment: Ah, true, because $b_n-\ell\to 0$ and meets the hypotheses of the usual theorem.

Comment: Yup, regardless, I believe it's a mistake. Go read about summation by parts.